# How can I list the URL of the page the data was scraped from with Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I'm a real beginner but I've been searching high and low and can't seem to find a solution. I'm working on building some spiders but I can't figure out how to identify what URL my scraped data comes from.

My spider is extremely basic right now, I'm trying to learn as I go.
I've tried a few lines I've found on stackoverflow but can't get anything working other than a print function (I can't remember if it was "URL: " + response.request.url or something similar. I tried a bunch of things) that worked in the parse section of the code but I can't get anything working in the yield.

I could add other identifiers in the output but ideally I'd like the URL for the project I'm working towards

```
import scrapy

class FanaticsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'fanatics'

    start_urls = ['https://www.fanaticsoutlet.com/nfl/new-england-patriots/new-england-patriots-majestic-showtime-logo-cool-base-t-shirt-navy/o-9172+t-70152507+p-1483408147+z-8-1114341320',
        'https://www.fanaticsoutlet.com/nfl/new-england-patriots/new-england-patriots-nfl-pro-line-mantra-t-shirt-navy/o-2427+t-69598185+p-57711304142+z-9-2975969489',]

    def parse(self, response):

        yield {
            'sale-price': response.xpath('//span[@data-talos="pdpProductPrice"]/span[@class="sale-price"]/text()').re('[$]\d+\.\d+'),
            #'sale-price': response.xpath('//span[@data-talos="pdpProductPrice"]/span[@class="sale-price"]/text()').get(),
            'regular-price': response.xpath('//span[@data-talos="pdpProductPrice"]/span[@class="regular-price strike-through"]/text()').re('[$]\d+\.\d+'),
            #'regular-price': response.xpath('//span[@data-talos="pdpProductPrice"]/span[@class="regular-price strike-through"]/text()').get(),
              }
```

Any help is much appreciated. I haven't begun to learn anything about pipeline yet, I'm not sure if that might hold a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the url in the *yield* like this:

```
yield {...,
       'url': response.url,
       ...}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I might have tried that but must have forgotten the comma at the end....*doh*

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.